# I cannot use discards in c#

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, c#-7.3

According to this link discards are supported since c# version 7.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards

If I write an `#error version` it says 7.3

[image: error version]

This code in the same MVC app doesn't work:

```
        public ActionResult SomeEndpoint()
        {
            return SomeResult(out _);
        }

        private ActionResult SomeResult(out int theInt)
        {
            theInt = 42;
            return View();
        }
```

The error is: `Error    CS0103  The name '_' does not exist in the current context`

What am I doing wrong?

Update: Is the target framework the problem? It's only 4.5.2.
[image]

I'm using visual studio 2019

Comment: To check - you're not making use of the `App_Code` directory in this project are you?

Comment: It looks correct... which is the error from the compiler?

Comment: @Damien there is no App_Code folder in my project

Comment: @Marco I've added the error

Comment: well, I agree: that should work; and locally it works fine, at least in a console exe; what exact setup is this? it may be relevant; also, I wonder if you might want to try simply *updating compiler* - locally, I have `4.2.0-2.22159.10 (f3a5bad2)`, so it sounds like there may be quite a bit of drift (although it would surprise me if this changed things)

Comment: Can the target framework be a problem? It's an older MVC app.

Comment: Using visual studio 2019

Comment: @gyozokudor in a .NET console application it works fine also with framework 4.5.2. I think the issue comes from the application context. It looks like a ASP.NET application and maybe this application context doesn't allow discards

Comment: @gyozokudor did you declare some kind of variable, class or anything else with name "_"? Maybe it's just a variable name error

Comment: Does anything change if you use `out int _`